# Does the C++11 standard guarantee the memory layout of initializer_list's objects are cross-compiler compatible?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, compatibility, initializer-list

vc++ implements the `std::initializer_list` as follows:

```
template<class T>
class initializer_list
{
public:
    // ...

private:
    const value_type* _first;
    const value_type* _last;
};
```

However, clang 3.4 implements the `std::initializer_list` in another way:

```
template<class T>
class initializer_list {
    const T* _p;
    size_t _size;
    // ...
};
```

Obviously, the two definitions are not binary-compatible with each other.

Why does the C++ standard not explicitly define the memory layout of `std::initializer_list` for compatibility?

Comment: C++ has never had binary compatibility for the standard library, and `std::initializer_list` is no exception. :S

Comment: I think Microsoft got it wrong once again ).

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't dictate "how" to do it but "what" to do (i.e., specifies behaviour). The "how" to do it is left as complement for the implementers.

Comment: The standard does not guarantee you binary compatibility of anything between different compilers. Even of two `int`s.

Comment: Man, am I glad that I made Clang recognize and correctly use both forms. At that point the MS library didn't have the definition, so that was purely speculative, but it paid off.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard specifically does not impose implementation details to allow an implementation to provide the functionality in a manner most efficient for the hardware being targeted. The language does not make you pay for functionality you don't need and generally allows for the compiler to make broad decisions to optimize the code for size/performance on given hardware. Specifying a specific ABI could force undue burden on compilers and compiled C++ programs.